# How to link an upload button to a download button on another page in Wix website builder?

Tags: velo

I need to **link a document** uploaded *by a member*.

Which is by **using** an `upload button` **to** a `download button` **on another page** in `Wix website builder`.

I **don't have any issue with programming it**, but I would **prefer not to** if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on exactly what you want, this could be doable without any code, or a minimal amount of code, and also using a database collection.

How you setup your collections will depend on exactly what you want to do, but it sounds like you will at least need one field that references one of the Members collections and another field to hold you file.

On the upload page, add a dataset (either write-only or read-write depending on you setup) for the collection and connect the upload button to that collection. Depending on your setup, you might need to write a line or two of code or use filters on the dataset to upload the file with the correct member info associated with it.

On the download page, you do pretty much the same thing. Add a collection (read-only) and connect the button to it. Again, you might have to filter the collection or write a bit of code to make sure you're getting the file that is associated with the current member.

Comment: So I need to set up 2 datasets, how will the download set pull data form the upload one? I need one page with 20 upload buttons and then 20 pages with one download button and make it so that the member with access to the upload page could change the data the buttons contain every week or so. What code and where would I will have to write it to implement my vision? Thanks for replying Sam.

Comment: I'm still not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve, so I can't give you a full answer.

But you certainly don't need 20 download pages. You probably want one dynamic page which will dynamically change what files are being downloaded based on the current member.

Comment: I am trying to create an intranet site for sales employees where an admin member upload sales objectives for the 20 employees, and I have 20 pages so I can have 20 groups of members containing one employee and admin each, so if some other employee tries to access someone's sales objectives they get directed to "Sorry you don't have access to this page.". I don't know how to do it with a dynamic page. As I said, I have created an Admin page and there I want to have upload buttons for each employee, but I don't know how to link those upload buttons to download buttons on employee pages.

Comment: But I'm failing at making the upload button to store the documents in a collection in the first place, I don't understand why. But all 20 buttons are connected to the dataset and have field type set to document, still when I go to the site with the admin member account and upload a dummy pdf. It doesn't show up anywhere. The permission and settings seem fine to me. Thanks for helping.